# Kotlin Sealed Class Inheritance

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using `Kotlin Sealed Class` for state management in Android.

```
sealed class StateA {
    data class State1(val s: String)
    object State2
    object State3
}
```

Now I need another `Sealed Class` for state management which shared a few states with `StateA` class.

```
sealed class StateB {
    data class State1(val s: String)
    object State2
    object State4
}
```

`data class State1` and `object State2` are identical in both `Sealed Classes`. I'm wondering if I can introduce an Inheritance (something like abstract classes) that both could share the states. Something like

```
sealed class SuperState {
    data class State1(val s: String)
    object State2
}
sealed class StateA: SuperState() {
    object State3
}

sealed class StateB: SuperState() {
    object State4
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I can't access for example `StateA.State1`.
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: In Kotlin (unlike in Java ) there is no static inheritance so there's no way to do what you want without declaring explicit getters in companion object. I also don't think you're using sealed classes correctly (your states don't inherit them) so they doesn't help you with declaring exhaustive switches.

Comment: Note that simply nesting objects/classes doesn't make them automatically inherit from the outer class. It should look more like `object State2 : StateA()`. As for having a sealed class extend another sealed class, that's possible as long as all classes are in the same source file. At least, I can get that to compile no problem. But trying to use a `when` expression doesn't seem to work (get an incompatible types error). Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @Pawel what is the correct way in this case.

Comment: @Slaw yes, I'm trying to use in a when condition but don't what to repeat the states in different sealed classes. Do you have a suggestion what is a better way?

Comment: It appears if you do `when (value)` where `value`'s static type is `SuperState` (e.g., `val value: SuperState = foo()`), then it will work. But in order to be exhaustive you have to have the implementations from each subtype (or an `else`, obviously). That would seem to defeat the purpose of trying to split the states into sealed subclasses.

Comment: But the question becomes, does `StateA.State1` and `StateB.State1` have the same semantic meaning? More specifically, does `StateA` and `StateB` have the same semantic meaning? If they don't, then it would make more sense to "duplicate" the code and have two independent sealed-class hierarchies. But if they do, then I would consider just having one sealed class, with all implementations inheriting from it. In other words, what is the reason for having both `StateA` and `StateB` in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, the current implementation of sealed classes is a bit weird. In my case, I use them for intents in MVI-architecture. Every action has an own intent and it is fine, but if I have a base class with base logic for 2 screens -> Huston I have a problem. In the result I have 2 ways: 1) throw out the sealed classes and use unstricted standard classes 2) remove the base class and duplicate logic in children classes. Very bad choice

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit counterintuitive at first sight, and it definitely is not as practicable as I would like to have it, as inheritors of sealed interfaces need to be in the exact same package (parent/child packages not working).

But if you inverse the inheritance you can get the behavior you want. This way the states become exhaustible when used with a `when` expression. Instead of having you concrete states inherit a base state, you need to inherit the concrete state in your base state.

If you think about it, sealed classes/interfaces are meant to define all possible subclasses at compile time. In your case you don't want `StateA/B` be a subclass of `SuperState`, but you actually want `SuperState` be a subclass of `StateA/B`. e.g. That would mean, an instance of `StateA` could be `State3` (as it is directly inherited from `StateA`) or one of the two states `State1`, `State2` (indirectly inherited from `SuperState` which extends `StateA`)

```kotlin
sealed interface SuperState : StateA, StateB {
    data class State1(val s: String) : SuperState
    data object State2 : SuperState
}

sealed interface StateA {
    data object State3 : StateA
}

sealed interface StateB {
    data object State4 : StateB
}

class Test {
    fun testSuper(state: SuperState) {
        when (state) {
            is SuperState.State1 -> TODO()
            SuperState.State2 -> TODO()
        }
    }

    fun testA(state: StateA) {
        when (state) {
            StateA.State3 -> TODO()
            is SuperState.State1 -> TODO()
            SuperState.State2 -> TODO()
        }
    }

    fun testB(state: StateB) {
        when (state) {
            StateB.State4 -> TODO()
            is SuperState.State1 -> TODO()
            SuperState.State2 -> TODO()
        }
    }
}
```